# how to encrypt the download for silverlight app?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-3.0, silverlight-5.0

when check "Reduce XAP size by using application caching" for silverlight app, the referenced assemblies can be compressed into separated zip files and downloaded by users when they access the app.

how to encrypt those zip files and xap file to protect your app?

Comment: What do you want to protect? You can configure your cached files to contain only non-sensitive stuff if you want.

Answer (score 0):

You need to treat the XAP like it was viewable jQuery.  Unless you obfuscate the code it will be pretty easy to look around and see what's going on, using reflector or something similar.  As mentioned in the comments, the transport for obtaining the XAP can be over HTTPS.  The way to secure what you're receiving from the client app is to not trust anything being sent by it.